# Iterm hotkey profile is not opening with current full screen app

Tags: macos, iterm2

I am trying to use iterm in full screen mode but problem I am facing it is, It always switch to another application in full screen mode in place of using current one. 
How to configure the hotkey window preference so it opens with current active full screen application?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by selecting `[] Native full screen windows` in the preferences -> General (right side)